# junit test with spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

I made the following test method for delete.
I get 200 ok when test status now I need to test that after calling the webservice the student was deleted
I use this code

```
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(s.getId().intValue()))
```

but get exception json can not be null or emty,Can anyone please help me how can i test delete method?

```
 @Test
 public void testDelete() throws Exception {
    Student s = data.getAll();
    ResultActions perform =    
    mockMvc.perform(delete(studentWebservice.URL+"/{id}",m.getId())
            );
    perform.andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(s.getId().intValue()))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value(s.name))
    ;
    }
```

Comment: why don't you omit the `.andExpect(json...)` assertions if you get an empty body as response? Usually `DELETE` operations return often a `HTTP 204 No Content` response to clearly state that there is no content anymore.